# How to follow the same height

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to follow the left side picture's height. But even if I tweak the padding for the right side picture, it still won't make it smaller like the left side.

Left side picture:

```dart
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(...)
        ),
        body: UpgradeAlert(
          canDismissDialog: false,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: Get.size.width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                ),
                child: SafeArea(
                  bottom: false,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 16.0, right: 16.0, top: 0.0, bottom: 16.0),
                    child:
```

Right side picture:

```
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
          title: Text('Test'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: Get.size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                ),
              ),
              child: const SafeArea(
                bottom: false,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 16.0, right: 16.0, top: 0.0, bottom: 16.0),
                ),
```

Edit: show picture separately.

Left side picture:
[image: Left side picture:]
Right side picture:
[image: Right side picture]
Side by side comparison to show the extra height in the right picture.
[image]

Comment: Can you try using `SafeArea` as parent widget for both ?

Comment: I already have it as a child. Once I set it as a parent widget, should I remove it as a child?

Comment: You can give a try, Can you include only full snippet of `Right image`'s code snippet and how you've used this widget? I've failed to reproduce the same issue

Comment: I tried it. Both became smaller in height but it is still not the same height. The left side is part of my main route. The right side is a new screen being called in my main route.

Comment: What happens while using `Test` as main route?

Comment: I tried that now, `Test` is still having that extra height.

Comment: I have shown both pictures separately. Although it might be hard to see the height difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom part is coming from `bottom` padding.

```dart
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
    left: 16.0,
    right: 16.0,
    top: 0.0,
  //  bottom: 16.0, you can remove this to have desire result
  ),
),
```

To get rounded corner, use  `shape` property on `AppBar`.

```dart
appBar: AppBar(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25.0),
      bottomRight: Radius.circular(25.0),
    ),
  ),
  backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
  title: Text('Test'),
),
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to remove the bottom, they now have the same height but now it doesn't become rounded. Also, why does the left side has 16 on the bottom but it shows differently?

Comment: You like to have app bar rounded corner?

Comment: Thanks for your ideas and answering my questions. It is now working as per my expectation. I didn't know that I couldn't just simply try to replicate the other one to make them the same.

Comment: Things was getting a little complicated while using `SafeArea< bottom: false>` and adding extra padding, you can follow [shape property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/shape.html)

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help. I will check on that.